# Regex that matches a pattern that does not occurr using Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a CSV file like with thousands of lines like these ones

```
40;206;343;-840;127.5;0;6
44;194;343;-837;127.5;0;6
48;183;343;-836;127.5;0;6
```

(7 fields separated by semicolumn).

However in a few cases there are some "errors" such as are more field separator or a missing field separator, e.g.

```
40;20;;6;343;-;840;127.5;0;6
4;4;194;343;-837;127.5;0;6
48;183;343;-836;;;;;6
```

How can I match these occurrences using Notepad++ (version 6+) using a regexp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match the valid csv format lines , you can use :

```
((?:[ \n\r]|^)\w+(?:;[\w.-]+){6}(?:[ \n\r]|&))
```

**[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/pP8wD0)**

**EXPLANATION :**

[image]

Comment: I love this diagram, where did it come from?

Answer (score 1):

SujithPS answer is correct, but for your data you could simplify the regex like that:

```
^(?:[^;]*;){6}[^;]*$
```

This will match the correct lines. You can test it at [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/hH4eE3).

If you want to select the incorrect lines, do the following:

1. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (or go to menu `Search` > `Find...`).
2. Then go to `Mark` tab.
3. Find what: `^(?:[^;]*;){6}[^;]*$`
4. Select the checkbox `Bookmark line` and the radio button `Regular expression`.
5. Then hit the `Mark` button.
6. Now you can inverse the bookmarked lines, through `Search` > `Bookmark` > `Inverse Bookmark`, and from the same menu you can delete them or whatever else.